# How to change the default layout for the active admin in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am new in ruby and generated an admin panel using devise and active admin but I want to change the default layout and design of whole active admin. I have researched this but mostly information is outdated and not providing a proper way to do this most of the information is incomplete.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I customize the active admin layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452418/how-can-i-customize-the-active-admin-layout)

Comment: Why not just monkey-patch the necessary views from here?
 https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/views

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate.  The original answer discusses how to override the Arbre views, my answer below is a plugin that uses an Erb template at the top level instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for changing theme of active admin 
https://github.com/paladini/activeadmin-themes

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to use my own theme??

Comment: Well, you can override the views from here, active admin does not generate a view but it programmatically generates a view, for more details you can have a look at view that is generated in this [link](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/views)

Comment: I have seen your provided link but my answer is still there that I want a method to override the default views.The material you have provided does not address my issue.

Comment: I have my own theme now what is the method/procedure/steps to override the default theme with my own theme?

Comment: Can you share which part you want to customise, footer, tabbed_navigation, header, tab as navigation?

Comment: I have metronic theme I want to change login,forgot password page and then the dashboard page. I want to modify them according to metronic theme.

Comment: specifically header, footer ,sidebar, content means according to my own theme.

Comment: Login Part, this is the view of [login](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/92ed4174bf9ced41193b2572711729d6daffeffa/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb),
Css of [login](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/d01155f73a0e2cc27d712792270357e2b3759d05/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/pages/_logged_out.scss).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155413/discussion-between-vaibhav-dhoke-and-john).

Comment: Changing themes changes CSS but not the layout.  An updated list of themes is maintained on the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Themes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ActiveAdmin custom layout plugin](https://github.com/bys-control/activeadmin_custom_layout).  However, if you find yourself wanting to customize everything consider whether you might be better off with regular Rails scaffolding, without ActiveAdmin.